# Infinite-scroll and limitTo doesn't display elements in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

The elements in the ng-repeat is filtered by toggling bools on the individual elements.

```
<div class="message-list" infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="1" infinite-scroll-parent="true">
     <div ng-repeat="powerplant in powerPlantFilter = (selectablePowerPlants | filter:searchString | limitTo: numberToDisplay) track by powerplant.ID">
           <div class="message" ng-show="powerplant.IsSelected === false && powerplant.IsInSegment === false">
                           ...     
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that, if I apply a certain filter, the first element that should be shown, is number 659 in the list.
If I haven't scrolled down so the numberToDisplay is higher than 659, no elements is shown in the list.
The numberToDisplay has a initial value of 35 and is incremented like this.

```
$scope.loadMore = function () {
    if ($scope.numberToDisplay + 20 < $scope.selectablePowerPlants.length) {
        $scope.numberToDisplay += 20;
    } else {
        $scope.numberToDisplay = $scope.selectablePowerPlants.length;
    }
};
```

How do I work around this problem?

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sraazzmv/25/) demonstrates the problem

Comment: Can you please make a working jsfiddle with the libraries included so I can try some ideas ?

Comment: Sure, i'll get one done as fast as possible

Comment: JsFiddle added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your problem.

Here is a working jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3Lsu2ojz/

Your problem what that you were using ng-show instead of a filter..

ng-show can be understood as 'put display: none !important; on this element if condition'

Consequently, it will still be taken in account in the infinite-scroll directive because elements are really here and limitTo actually does its job.

You can use a custom filter, in your case :

```
$scope.searchString = {'ShowMe': true }
```

Does the trick.

Also consider using this syntax instead of yours :

```
powerplant in powerPlantsFilter = ( selectablePowerPlants | 
                                filter:searchString | 
                                limitTo: numberToDisplay) track by powerplant.ID"
```

Where powerPlantsFilter is here not a collection from the scope but a collection dynamically created by the spec of limitTo and filter.